# What is the terminology name for AWS EFS NFS service endpoint?

Tags: endpoint, amazon-efs

I'm trying to find the terminology name for AWS EFS NFS endpoint.
When creating an EFS file system, AWS automatically creates an network interface and attaches it to the EFS, and the DNS name for this NIC is `fs-XXXXXX.efs.<region>.amazonaws.com`. This endpoint is the one providing NFS service.
AWS also provides VPC interface endpoint for EFS and the DNS name is `elasticfilesystem.<region>.amazonaws.com`. This interface endpoint is not providing NFS service, but providing API service for EFS in this particular region.
The latter has a name `VPC interface endpoint`. But I couldn't find the terminology name for the former endpoint, `fs-XXXXXX.efs.<region>.amazonaws.com`. And I couldn't find the documentation for this endpoint.
Anyone can help?